# subtotals coming in new page for crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

[image]I have a group and sometimes details are coming in one page and the sub total alone coming in a new page which I don't want.
Please suggets how to do

Comment: Please show us the crystal report design view ?

Comment: your requirement is incomplete... if details fill the whole page then automatically sub total will come in new page.. what is your exact requirement?

Comment: Hi Siva I have a group and the sub totals of that group should not come in new page alone.Either it should come in same page or it should come in nextpage with some details section values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the keep group toguether option. Here is a tutorial : http://www.itsupportguides.com/crystal-reports/crystal-reports-keep-group-on-same-page/

Comment: Hi Alex, I don't want to check keep group together which will waste the space in page if my group data is not fitting in the same page.Please suggest any workaround

Comment: Put the snapshot of ur report Design. That would help better.